# Why GZipStream remove whitespaces?

Tags: c#, .net, compression, gzip

I use GZipSream to compress and decompress text file. But there is no whitespaces in decompressed file.

My code for compress:

```
    using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            using (FileStream targetStream = File.Create(compressedFile))
            {
                using (GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(targetStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                {
                    sourceStream.CopyTo(compressionStream);                         
                }
            }
        }
```

For decompress:

```
    using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(compressedFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            using (FileStream targetStream = File.Create(targetFile))
            {
                using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(sourceStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    decompressionStream.CopyTo(targetStream);                      
                }
            }
        }
```

Example uncompressed input:

```
  2018-11-13 00:02:40,574 76     INFO
```

Decompressed:

```
  2018-11-1300:02:40,57476INFO
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce with your code, white space from `sourceFile` appears in `targetFile`

Comment: @steve16351, What do you mean?

Comment: Can you provide [mcve]? I also can not reproduce results: https://tio.run/##tVRda8IwFH1ef8WlL7agpXVuDosPw@EQ5goqDPbWtRcJ1KYk6TaR/nbXT5uuFZyw@9Byk5tzcu5J4vGBRxkejzEn4RbWey5wZytyZiyc1oAxo7uIIeeEhrbChSuIB1H8EaQ/L3A5hw1yAQcF0mhOf1Liw9IloaaX81l4NEzruWAZDacx83BOAoQpqEWm2t21XrkR9Kv6euTcGuGyLYqqvsjSWuUmGzLeGBH4GAQb/BZavZU@qABD03oYWNbAugXTnJjDycjs341HML7PWRavcwdA1TOsomNatnQtGLq7UlaZTCHEL6hnG0zZd0l9NJwIQ4fN0gKBun5SU/ctizZTIenElMsqQLRmvyTMNq6E/fxOohLOq51vSKlLNJm@D9JRyTVV@S/ubv78/Eh9S1dH@w3VWrvQbTgXLdBE6c6SK2xr9vNfrauP7RW2@XiBcbLUtnFPJ4iLretgrRyUhZ4z70/OzdIrTqv7@0JC1NQV8jgQE@gdzKSnFuYYK3T96nrLLS0ei0RJjscf

Comment: @ensiferum what I mean is the code you show doesn't have the problem that you describe, `GZipStream` does not remove white space. The problem is elsewhere.